# Basic sound error in Matlab

Tags: matlab, audio

I have the following Matlab function to produce a sound:

```
function [] = makesound( )

    cf = 2000;                  % carrier frequency (Hz)
    sf = 22050;                 % sample frequency (Hz)
    d = 1.0;                    % duration (s)
    n = sf * d;                 % number of samples
    s = (1:n) / sf;             % sound data preparation
    s = sin(2 * pi * cf * s);   % sinusoidal modulation
    sound(s, sf);               % sound presentation
    pause(d + 0.5);             % waiting for sound end

end
```

However when I run the code, I get the following error:

```
??? Error using ==> sound
Too many input arguments.

Error in ==> makesound at 14
sound(Beep,rate);
```

What is wrong?

Comment: Your code works for me... I get a beep with no errors. I'm running R2011b.

Comment: Do you have another variable/function in your workspace called `sound`? Does `help sound` confirm that `sound` on your version of Matlab takes two arguments?

Comment: The code, as is, works for me as well.

Comment: when I type "help sound" it says "No help found for sound.m". How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably have some function in your path, 'name hiding' a Matlab function. This function takes a smaller number of input arguments then Matlab's, therefore the `Too many input arguments`. 
[In my case](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15322696/501663) it was `assert` that caused the problem, in your case it could be anything. Walk step-by-step with the debugger (using F11 to jump into all functions you have along the way) till you find the place where some function fails. Then make sure the path where the problematic function sits, is at the bottom of Matlab's path list, so the default call is made to Matlab's function.