# Error trying to play sound

Tags: matlab, audio

Similar to this question [Basic sound error in Matlab](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9369833/501663) (with no answer), When I try to play a sound (Matlab 2012a, Windows 7 64bit), using either `sound`,`soundsc`, or `audioplayer`, I get an error:

```
>> load chirp.mat;
>> soundsc(y,Fs)
Error using sound (line 60)
Too many input arguments.

Error in soundsc (line 48)
sound(varargin{:})
```

I suspect it's a device driver issue, but it's just a guess. Matlab seems to see the audio devices:

```
>> devinfo = audiodevinfo;
>> devinfo.output.Name
ans =
Primary Sound Driver (Windows DirectSound)
ans =
Speakers (High Definition Audio Device):1 (Windows DirectSound)
ans =
Speakers (High Definition Audio Device):2 (Windows DirectSound)
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that a function in my Matlab path was 'name hiding' one of Matlab's own functions. Unfortunately, it was the `assert` function, which was buried deep in the call stack so it took me some time to spot. In addition, I was trying to understand why the assert fails when the condition it checks was perfectly true...